# data noupdate="0" & "1" in Security.xml

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Please explain the mean of below statements and state the difference between them.
I go through forum posts but not got clear idea from those and documentations also not mention those stuffs.

I got below code from **sale_security.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data noupdate="0">
```

and

```
<data noupdate="1">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<data noupdate="1">` means this file load only initial time, means only first time of installation `--init=module`, after that this file never load and update

`<data noupdate="0">`  means this file load and update every time you update the file when you start with `--update=module`

Comment: wat abt 'ir.rule' records in ...security.xml files & which relation with 'res.groups' records

Comment: ir.rule is used with groups, like in sale order you want a case that every user just see his own record not other user sale order, so you make a record rule in ir.rule to stop other user to see each other sale order, and assign this rule to some group when you assing this group to user it automatically apply this rule

Comment: Dear friend,
here updated that question.please update it :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234383/openerp-ir-rule-records-in-security-xml